# How can I change the resolution of a PDF

Tags: pdf

I have scanned a document into a PDF at 300dpi.  The document file is larger than I would like.  Is there a simple way to down-sample the document so that it has a lower resolution?  Or do I just need to re-scan the original document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)'s [scale](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#scale) or [resize](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#percent) operators.

> ImageMagick® is a software suite to create, edit, compose, or convert
>   bitmap images. It can read and write images in a variety of formats
>   (over 100) including DPX, EXR, GIF, JPEG, JPEG-2000, PDF, PhotoCD,
>   PNG, Postscript, SVG, and TIFF.

For example, from a terminal:

```
convert input.pdf  -resize 50% output.pdf
```

or

```
convert input.pdf -scale 50% output.pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

Apple's Preview comes with a feature allowing you to save a file with a reduced file size.

Open your file in Preview, and click File>Save As.

Scroll down to the bottom where you will see a "Quartz Filter" drop-down menu and choose "Reduce File Size".

If you want to retain a copy of your original but larger file size, rename this file and click save.  Otherwise you will overwrite the larger file when you click save.

Comment: I have very bad experiences with this tool. There is little control for the user as to how much the resolution is lowered. In most cases, the text pdfs that I use are unreadable when applying this filter.

Comment: If you aren't afraid of some harmless XML editing, you can create custom quality size reduction filters for `Preview`. http://www.macworld.com/article/1168311/software/shrink-preview-files-without-ruining-image-quality.html explains how.